Why is VueJS Routers savedPosition always 0? How can I store the scroll position by myself?
I have a strange issue with the VueJS Router and its built-in scrollBehaviour-feature.
I want to achieve that on back-navigation, the browser would scroll down to the original position where the user previously clicked for navigation into a child page.
I am using the built-in ScrollBehaviour Feature: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior
My implementation is this:
  const router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
      if (savedPosition) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Saved Position:', savedPosition)
            resolve({ left: 0, top: savedPosition.top, y: savedPosition.top, behavior: 'smooth' });
          }, 800)
        })
      } else {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
          }, 800)
        })
      }
    },

So far, it doesn't work well. It most of the cases, the savedPosition is just top: 0.
Google Chrome Desktop: works mostly always, sometimes not
Google Chrome on iOS: don't work at all
Safari Desktop Mac: don't work at all. savedPosition is always `top: 0`
Safari iOS: don't work at all. savedPosition is always `top: 0`

Apparently I have to save the scroll position by myself. How can I do this and where?

It's unknown how you navigated to observe this. Please, provide a way to reproduce, as this is clearly something that needs to be debugged

i think i had the same problem, and "scroll-behaviour" feature didnt work for me either. in one of my projects i did this:

in router i added meta: { saveScrollPosition: true }, to routes i wanted to have scroll positions saved

then just using beforeEach:
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
setTimeout(() => {
 if (from.meta.saveScrollPosition) {
     saveScrollPosition(from.path, window.scrollY);
   }
     next();
   }, 0);
});


scrollManager.js:
 let scrollPositions = {};

 export function saveScrollPosition(path, position) {
   scrollPositions[path] = position;
 }

 export function getScrollPosition(path) {
   return scrollPositions[path] || 0;
 }


then in every page i wanted the scroll to be restored(this is homepage as an example):
 onMounted(() => {
   const scrollY = getScrollPosition("/home");
   window.scroll(0, scrollY);
 });


and dont forget imports import { getScrollPosition } from "@/scrollManager";


i feel like this is kind of barbaric, but it worked for me at that time.

Nice approach, thanks! I have implemented it. However, for our case, it causes some bad side effects. We serve the same Page for multiple categories and once one clicks on the menu to select another category, we need to use another key for the Scrollmanager. But: it's all doable and better than the built-in thing that didnt work. Thank you!
